# Calculating frequency

Tags: php, algorithm, calculation

I'm creative a forum and want to calculate the frequency of new posts per day. So, each post has timestamps:

```
$post_1 = 1526083200;
$post_2 = 1524083200;
$post_3 = 1523083200;
$post_4 = 1522083200;
```

What calculation do I do to find out how often posts are submitted **per day**. Example final output:

```
echo 'Every '. $frequency .' day(s)';
```

Comment: How do you get those value?

Comment: @MickaelLeger They are stored in the database.

Comment: You can maybe try to make a select to get the sum or article by day and calculate the frequency with `(number of post) / (number of day selected)` no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maybe try something like this :

```
$post_1 = 1526083200;
$post_2 = 1524083200;
$post_3 = 1523083200;
$post_4 = 1522083200;

// I add all the value in an array then sort the array to get the min and max value
$date_array = [$post_1, $post_2, $post_3, $post_4];
sort($date_array);

// Now I can select the min date and the max date
$min_date = $date_array[0];
$max_date = $date_array[count($date_array) - 1];

// I calculate the diff to get the number of day during this period
$datediff = $max_date - $min_date;

// I divide this value with the number or article post during this period
$frequency = $datediff / count($date_array);

// Now I transform this value in number of day
$frequency = round($frequency / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

With your example, this is what you got :

- Number of articles : `4`
- Min date : `2018-03-26`
- Max date : `2018-05-12`
- Number of day of the period : `46`
- Frequency : `12`

That sound good for me with those value , one article every 12 days.

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: The solution was what you posted as a comment: `(number of post) / (number of day selected)`

Comment: So with your example the frequency you want is `4 / 46 = 0.0869` ? So one posts every 12 days at a frequency of 0.0869 per day?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want the general frequency:

- frequency = 1 / period
- period = average time between two posts = time between oldest and newest post / number of post - 1
- time between oldest and newest post = newest post - oldest post

In your example:

```
$post_1 = 1526083200;
$post_2 = 1524083200;
$post_3 = 1523083200;
$post_4 = 1522083200;
```

- time between oldest and newest posts = 1526083200 - 1522083200 = 4000000 seconds = 46,2962963 Days
- period = 46,2962963/3 = 15.4320987667 Days (There is on average 15 days between two posts)
- frequency = 1 / 15.4320987667 = 0.06479999999 (There is on average one post each 0.0648 Days)

Comment: Can you please demonstrate this in code using the timestamp variables above? The aim is frequency *per day*.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson maybe I misunderstood what you wanted, hope it's more clear with example